# Void * input to function loses address when function ends

Tags: c, pointers, types

i am new to C lang. My code is like:

```
int afunc(const struct datas *mydata, void *value) {
    value = &mydata->astring; // astring is in structure char[20]
    return 0;
}

int main (...) {
    ...
    const char *thevalue;
    if (!afunc(thedata, &thevalue) {...}
    ...
}
```

The address in var value is only in the function, when the function is over variable thevalue is still empty... So, I want pointer on array in the structure.

How should I fix that?

Comment: You are passing a `void *` variable and than you are overwriting the variable... if you want to save data into the location pointed to by the pointer, you might consider dereferencing it. If you're trying to save a pointer, consider using a `void **` pointer (than dereferencing that: `*value = &mydata->astring`.

Comment: `*(const char **)value = mydata->astring;` [fix DEMO](http://ideone.com/o7MB8a)

Comment: Thank you so much guys... BLUEPIXY your solution is just what i need...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fix like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct datas {
    char astring[20];
};

int afunc(const struct datas *mydata, void *value) {
    *(const char **)value = mydata->astring;
    return 0;
}

int main (void) {
    struct datas mydata = { "test_data" }, *thedata = &mydata;
    const char *thevalue;
    if (!afunc(thedata, &thevalue)) {
        puts(thevalue);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You use pointers to pass variables which must be modified in C. However, if you want to modify a pointer value, you must pass a pointer to that pointer, and then dereference the pointer in the function. Like this:

```
int afunc(const struct datas *mydata, void **value) {
    *value = &mydata->astring; // astring is in structure char[20]
    return 0;
}

int main (...) {
    ...
    const char *thevalue;
    if (!afunc(thedata, &thevalue) {...}
    ...
}
```